# Substracting birthday year with the current year

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, subtraction

I've started learning PHP, and just can't figure out how to accomplish this.
The basic question is to how to calculate age from current year..

I have to do it with a submit button, and that's the problem for me. I tried this:

```
<form name="form2" action="16.1.php" method="POST">
Birthday year:
<input type="post" name="post">
<input type="submit" value= "Verstuur" >
</form>
```

16.1php:

```
<?php
echo date ('Y') - $_POST['post'];
?>
```

Comment: and what error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating this..

```
<input type="input" name="post">
```

`type = "post"` to `type = "input"`

Comment: Thanks.. didn't knew it was that easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if($_POST['submit'])

```
{
$byear = $_POST['bdate']; 
$today = new DateTime();
$birthdate = new DateTime($byear);
$interval = $today->diff($birthdate);
echo $interval->format('%y years');
}
```

---

```
<form name="form2" action="" method="POST">
Birthday year:
<input type="text" name="bdate">(yyy-mm-dd)
<input type="submit" name="submit" value= "Verstuur" >
</form>
```

---